# pyserial read variable byte array

Tags: python, arrays, pyserial

I am writing a code that can flexibly read a mutable array (4 byte array and 7 byte array).

I don't think it's a good idea to read 7 bytes continuously and judge it by the number of bytes sent in the 2nd byte.
Reading an array that is sent in 4 bytes as 7 bytes results in slow reception.

```
serial_port = serial.Serial(
    port="/dev/ttyUSB0",
    baudrate=9600,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True :
        
        time.sleep(1)
        if serial_port.readable():
            serial_port.flushInput()
            serial_port.timeout = None
            data =serial_port.read(7)
            l_data=list(data)
                   
            print("Header : " , str.join("", ("0x%02X " % i for i in l_data)))
```

Results received from connected equipment

ouput:

```
Header :  0x2B 0x04 0x53 0x7C 0x2B 0x04 0x53   #0x04 is the actual total number of byte
Header :  0x2b 0x07 0x51 0x06 0x07 0x46 0x3a   #0x07 is the actual total number of byte
```

If I replace `read()` with `readline()`, nothing comes up.
So did `read_until()`.
(Actually, it is because of my lack of skills.)

I tried to find a solution to find the end of the array (`\n` or `\r`) and truncate it, but it didn't work.

Is there a way to flexibly receive 4 bytes and 7 bytes?